# Vector autoregression model with unit root in the exogenous variable and endogenous variables

Tags: vector-autoregression, unit-root, vector-error-correction-model

I was wondering whether I should worry about the fact that I have **one** unit root in my exogenous variable. I think based on what I understand that I should first difference the variable with unit root, before using it in my VAR. Can someone verify whether this is correct?

Second, I was also wondering, suppose I have multiple unit roots, but they are all in my exogenous variables, I guess I should then test for cointegration. However if I find them to be cointegrated, should I then switch to a vector error correction model? Or do I just difference them and then add them to my VAR?

In addition, I was also wondering, suppose I have one exogenous variable that has a unit root and an endogenous variable that has a unit root, should I then test both of them for cointegration? If yes, and I find cointegration, what should I do?

Hopefully someone can shine some light upon this, because I am having difficulties figuring this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not an expert of this topic, but here is what seems reasonable to me.

**Case 1:** all endogenous variables are stationary, one exogenous variable is integrated (has a unit root).
I would take first differences of the integrated exogenous variable and include that in the VAR model. You *cannot* include levels of an integrated variable because you would end up with a stationary variable on the left hand side and a non-stationary combination (made up of some stationary variables and one non-stationary variable) on the right hand side, which is a contradiction.

**Case 2:** all endogenous variables are stationary, some exogenous variables are integrated.
**A:** If the exogenous variables are *not* cointegrated, include their first differences just as in Case 1.
**B:** If the exogenous variables are cointegrated, include both their first differences and the stationary combinations (error correction terms).
In both **A** and **B** cases the left-hand-side variables will be the regular endogenous variables. My answer is about what to include on the right hand side.

**Case 3:** one endogenous variable is integrated, one exogenous variables is integrated.
**A:** If the two variables are *not* cointegrated, include their first differences just as in Case 2A.
**B:** If the two variables are cointegrated, include both their first differences and their stationary combination (the error correction term).
In both **A** and **B** cases the left-hand-side variables will be the regular endogenous variables *except for the integrated one* which is replaced by its own first differences. My answer is about what to include on the right hand side.